# Filtering only 1 column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set like this with columns and rows independent of each other
dUMMY DATA

```
ColumnA(Days)  ColumnB(Status of ColumnA)  ColumnC(Control)    ColumnD(Status of columnC)
Monday         At Risk                     access               At Risk
Tuesday        Delayed                     Coverage             Delayed
Weds           Complete                     Gaps                 Delayed
```

So i want a situation where if i filter columnB, it only shows me ColumnA since i want to see the status of ColumnA only. Thank you

Comment: There is no way to not affect any other columns present in a view if you filter on any column. As such, put ColumnB in filters tab to achieve your desired result.

Comment: what is your desired output if you filter any value in Column B?

Comment: I actually did put Column B in filter Tab but all columns still show. The only information i put in the columns are Column A and Column C while Column B and Column D are in the filter Tab to enable me filter status of Column A and C. Despite that Both Column A and C still shows when i filter column B to get information for only Column A.

Comment: My desired output should be that only information of status of Column A should show when column B is in the Filter Tab.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how filters work in Tableau. If you add '`ColumnB`' to filter and excluded '`At Risk`', then everything in that first row `(Monday`, `At Risk`, `access`, `At Risk`) will be excluded. 
If you want to show only `ColumnA`, then add that to the view. Then add `ColumnB` to filter. Select which `ColumnB` values you want to filter and that is all you need to do. E.g. if you include only 'At Risk' in the filter, then only Monday (`columnA`) will display.

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct way to do this. Maybe it is possible through creation of calculated fields and parameters. But if your target columns are large in number then it would become quite tedious for you. Ask your question on the Tableau platform here: https://community.tableau.com. There are quite a few experts that may be able to help you out.

Comment: @mkmkmk123. Thanks for your response. However, i actully need both columns A and C to be on the view, while Columns B and D would be the filters to status of respective columns.

Comment: @r.uckus. Thank you. i would check out the community as you suggested. Hopefully i get inputs from Tableau Experts.

Comment: @Ajay Based on the original question and the comment here, perhaps a dashboard with two worksheets (one with A+B and the other with C+D) might get you close to something. You can add action filters etc. to they are interlinked. However filtering something on Column B will affect Column A (like you need), but also Columns C and D (sounds like you don't want that). There is no way around that when they are in the same view with this kind of data structure.